# Place UIImageViews Randomly on UIView and not overlap

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimageview

What I am doing is placing `UIImageViews` randomly on the view, I have that part working all I am doing is this:

```
return (int)0 + arc4random() % (self.view.bounds.frame.size.height-0+1);
```

and also for the width.

What I am running into is some of the `UIImageViews` overlap each other. I know I can use `CGRectIntersectsRect` but how can I loop though it until all `UIImageViews` are not overlapping each other?

Comment: Before you return a new CGRect to use as the frame for an imageview, loop through a new array containing the views and check if CGRectIntersectsRect; if it does then either adjust the frame or generate another.

Comment: @Luke: this should be in answer....not here.

Comment: True, but I prefer to throw in a tidbit and see if this is something the OP is interested in. :)

Comment: @Luke I tried that, but what was happening is when it would pick a new CGRect and move the image it sometimes would still overlap but a different image. Is there away to keep looping until nothing is touching?

Comment: Add more code to your question that shows this attempt - sounds like it's not totally correct.

Comment: @Luke I reread your comment and I read it wrong the first time. I am not doing what you suggested. How would I go about doing what you suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how you may modify your current method(s) to place the imageviews, as described in my earlier comment:

```
// make sure this array is a member object, else pass it to the makeFrame method below.
NSArray *imageviews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: view1, view2, view3, nil]; // make sure they have tags! set the .tag property of each imageview in the array.
UIView *mainView = nil; // this won't really be nil - this is the view you are adding your imageviews to.

for (int i = 0; i < [imageviews count]; i++)
{
    UIImageView *imageview = [imageviews objectAtIndex: i];
    CGRect newFrame = [self makeFrameForView: imageview];

    while (newFrame.origin.x == 0 && newFrame.origin.y == 0)
    {
        // then the method returned CGRectZero. create it again until we get a good frame.
        newFrame = [self makeFrameForView: imageview];
    }

    [imageview setFrame: newFrame];
}


-(CGRect)makeFrameForView: (UIImageView*)theImageView
{
    CGRect newFrame = nil; // create your new frame here using arc4random etc and the parameters you prefer.

    for (int i = 0; i < [imageviews count]; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *imageview = [imageviews objectAtIndex: i];

        // first, ensure you aren't checking the same view against itself!
        if (theImageView.tag != imageview.tag)
        {
            BOOL intersectsRect = CGRectIntersectsRect(imageview.frame, newFrame);

            if (intersectsRect)
                return CGRectZero; // throw an "error" rect we can act upon.

        }
    }

    return newFrame;
}
```

Comment: @Xeieshan Please feel free to make a new question to fully describe the problem you are having - the code above is quite straightforward and but one way of solving the OP's issue.

Comment: How can i set custom height and width in CGRect newFrame?

I have to pass height and width in 

for (int i = 0; i < [imageviews count]; i++)
{

}

Comment: @Parthpatel1105 Where `CGRect newFrame = nil;` is setup in the `makeFrameForView:` method is where you can define the frame size that you require :)